# Parsing unsigned int of a known size

Tags: c++, parsing

I am parsing string, and I expect to parse number with 6 digits. I also know that the number is with 6 digits, so it will fit unsiged int.

what way is better to parse it?
using atoi and then casting into unsigned int or using strtoul (which returns unsigned long int) and then casting into unsigned int?

is there another way I didn't think of?
thanks

Comment: Another possibility: `sscanf(str, "%u", &var)`

Answer (score 1):

if you know how your string will look like, you can simply use `sscanf`

```
sscanf(yourStringBuffer, "%ud", &unsingedIntVariable);
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, the easiest version would be [`stoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) in C++.

```
unsigned int i = stoul(str);
```

But if you want to do it directly and this is really time critical you can also do it explicitly, since you know the number of digits:

```
unsigned int i =
  static_cast<unsigned int>(str[5]-'0') * 1ul
+ static_cast<unsigned int>(str[4]-'0') * 10ul
+ static_cast<unsigned int>(str[3]-'0') * 100ul
+ static_cast<unsigned int>(str[2]-'0') * 1000ul
+ static_cast<unsigned int>(str[1]-'0') * 10000ul
+ static_cast<unsigned int>(str[0]-'0') * 100000ul;
```

But I would strongly recommend going with `stoul`.

Comment: You can't use bitmasks for everything, bitmask! `|` doesn't work here -- you have to use `+`.

Comment: @TonyK: You are absolutely correct! Thank you. Don't know what I was thinking!